# SQL query for select count date from fields record

Tags: mysql, sql

I want sql query to select records from my advertisement tables thats expiration
count date under 7 days.
My code is:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM advertisement WHERE DAY( FROM_UNIXTIME( expiration ) ) <=7";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$rec=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

### but its not returning true. My expiration field is timestamp, please help me for best query with best performance, thank you.

**thank you everybody for answered myquestion i tested it and true:**

```
SELECT * FROM advertisement where datediff(FROM_UNIXTIME( expiration ),now()) <=7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you. If you want to have all records the expire in less than seven days, this will do the trick:

```
select * from advertisement
where datediff(current_day + interval 7 day,FROM_UNIXTIME( expiration )) < 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

$query ="SELECT * FROM advertisement WHERE NOW()-expiration<=7";

Now would give the current timestamp and subtracting it from expiration timestamp will give you the no. of days.